# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'network' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, data-science, geopandas

I am trying to use geopandas but am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'network' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

I am using Jupyter and am installing following dependencies

```
%conda install numpy
%conda install pandas
%pip install geopandas
%conda install -c plotly plotly
%conda install -c conda-forge pyarrow
%conda install scikit-learn
%pip install ipdb
%pip install --upgrade certifi
%pip install geopandas
```

I then import the following dependencies

```
import argparse
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from ipdb import set_trace
from math import sin, cos, sqrt, atan2, radians
from pyod.models.lscp import LSCP
from pyod.models.lof import LOF
from pyod.utils.utility import standardizer
from pyod.utils.data import generate_data
from pyod.utils.data import evaluate_print
from pyod.utils.example import visualize
from scipy.stats import zscore
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree, KDTree
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest
from sklearn.neighbors import LocalOutlierFactor
```

When I take out `%pip install --upgrade certifi` I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'certifi' has no attribute 'where'
```

I get the following traceback for the certifi error:

```
    AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-c307bc851b37> in <module>
          1 import argparse
          2 import os
    ----> 3 import geopandas as gpd
          4 import plotly.express as px
          5 import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
    ----> 1 from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
          2 
          3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
          4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
          5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py in <module>
        124 use_pygeos = Option(
        125     key="use_pygeos",
    --> 126     default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
        127     doc=(
        128         "Whether to use PyGEOS to speed up spatial operations. The default is True "
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py in _default_use_pygeos()
        110 
        111 def _default_use_pygeos():
    --> 112     import geopandas._compat as compat
        113 
        114     return compat.USE_PYGEOS
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py in <module>
          6 
          7 import pandas as pd
    ----> 8 import pyproj
          9 import shapely
         10 import shapely.geos
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py in <module>
         78     warnings.warn(str(err))
         79 
    ---> 80 pyproj.network.set_ca_bundle_path()
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyproj/network.py in set_ca_bundle_path(ca_bundle_path)
         49         env_var_name in os.environ for env_var_name in env_var_names
         50     ):
    ---> 51         ca_bundle_path = certifi.where()
         52     else:
         53         # reset CA Bundle path to use system settings
    
    AttributeError: module 'certifi' has no attribute 'where'
```

I get the following error when I install certifi:

```
    ------ AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-5-c307bc851b37> in <module>
          1 import argparse
          2 import os
    ----> 3 import geopandas as gpd
          4 import plotly.express as px
          5 import plotly.graph_objects as go
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/__init__.py in <module>
    ----> 1 from geopandas._config import options  # noqa
          2 
          3 from geopandas.geoseries import GeoSeries  # noqa
          4 from geopandas.geodataframe import GeoDataFrame  # noqa
          5 from geopandas.array import points_from_xy  # noqa
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py in <module>
        124 use_pygeos = Option(
        125     key="use_pygeos",
    --> 126     default_value=_default_use_pygeos(),
        127     doc=(
        128         "Whether to use PyGEOS to speed up spatial operations. The default is True "
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_config.py in
    _default_use_pygeos()
        110 
        111 def _default_use_pygeos():
    --> 112     import geopandas._compat as compat
        113 
        114     return compat.USE_PYGEOS
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_compat.py in <module>
          6 
          7 import pandas as pd
    ----> 8 import pyproj
          9 import shapely
         10 import shapely.geos
    
    ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyproj/__init__.py in <module>
         78     warnings.warn(str(err))
         79 
    ---> 80 pyproj.network.set_ca_bundle_path()
    
    AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pyproj' has no attribute 'network' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: Please, check [ask] and post the full traceback you get.

Comment: Sorry new to stackoverflow. I have taken your response and improved my question